# Single or two word(s) for Task Assigned to me and its status

Tags: single-word-requests

I need to maintain work sheet,For that I need to mention Project name in one column and in 2nd column i need to mention Task Assigned to me and its status. So I want to know how can I name 2nd column with Single or two word(s). Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest term for the work or task you have been "assigned" to complete would be, "**assignment**." As for status of the assignments, simply add a **forward-slash** ( / ) after assignment, thus "**assignment / status**".

> **assignment** *noun*: plural noun: **assignments**
>
> **1**. a task or piece of work assigned to someone as part of a job or course of study.
>   "a homework assignment"
>
> *synonyms*: task, piece of work, job, duty, chore, mission. see, Google.com ["**assignment**"](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=navclient&ie=UTF-8&rlz=1T4VRHB_enUS620US620&q=assignment+definition&gws_rd=ssl)

Comment: But what about status of that work? How to name that along with assignments

Comment: How would "assignment/status" work?

Comment: So do I need to maintain assignment and its status in different columns?

Comment: yes I have. I can use like this this..